# tf::createQuaternionFromYaw equivalent in ros2

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How should I create a quaternion of a simple yaw (zaxis) rotation in ros2?

The alternative in ros1 were essentially `tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw` or `tf::createQuaternionFromYaw` but these options are not there anymore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364561/tf::createquaternionfromyaw-equivalent-in-ros2/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know there is no out of the box `tf`/`tf2` function that does that in ros2.

However, you can easily achieve that with a simple helper function e.g.:

```
auto createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(double yaw)
{
  tf2::Quaternion q;
  q.setRPY(0, 0, yaw);
  return tf2::toMsg(q);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) with karma: 218 on 2020-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2